# Is it wrong to answer a 2 months old question that hasn't been answered properly?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've come across a question about HTML on Stack Overflow, which hasn't been clearly answered, then, I decided to contribute and answer it. However, I didn't realize 2 months had passed since and I feel like the OP already found the answer or lost interest in the aforementioned question.

Does the Stack Exchange network have specific rules against "Necroposting" or anything related to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it isn't wrong at all. There are even two badges, Revival and Necromancer for this purpose.

We encourage that every question be answered, no matter how old it is. We even encourage questions with good answers that are several years be answered again if those answers aren't up-to-date, and you want to add your own answer.

So, whenever you think you have an answer to a question, go post it.